# File browser Tree Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to add a FRame to my Tkinter GUI in which there is a file browser as a tree to browse file and select a specific one. I tried to add the open button but I am looking to make it appear as a default frame from the GUI.
is there any example that may help me? thanks.

Comment: Are you aware of [ttk.Treeview](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html)

Comment: yes but to populate it with all files and folder seems complex and time confusion

Comment: Why don't you use [Standard Dialog - Selecting Files and Directories](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/windows.html#dialogs)